# Reference another piece of text in a Google Drive Document?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to reference another piece of text in a Google Drive Document. In a similar way to how you can reference data in another cell in a Google Drive Spreadsheet ?

Eg. I have a document reference name something like "My Doc - ABC - 123" at the top of my document.

I need to re write this text in multiple places, but don't want to change it in multiple places if it change the document reference name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to put your reference text at the top or bottom  of every page (except perhaps the first one), then you can use the **Insert > Header and page number > Header** (or Footer) menu option to put in a page-header.

(see [an example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rJ8vfoQ_Bcv4VtfQf7KmR1k-c8C_R2RT3AZjmiuUVw0/edit?usp=sharing) of this)

Alternatively, if you know that the contents of your reference text only appears in places that you want changed, then you can use use the **Edit > Find and replace > Replace all** tool to quickly update it.

Or you could construct your document with Sheets instead of Docs:  the feature you've described is something which spreadsheets are very good at doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save time via keystrokes I recommend checking out `www.autohotkey.com` or have a look in the help menu for custom short cut options and paste in your commonly used phrases as the output